How to proxy to Atlantis websocket using Flask
I need to proxy to Atlantis using Flask. Atlantis is serving up a website to display the progress of terraform plan or terraform apply. The majority of the backend URLs are static resources, so these can be proxied using a Flask route:
@app.route('/prefix/<path:path'>)
def a_path(path):
  ... perform proxying here, just make sure content-type headers are returned correctly

However, there is one URL that the backend serves up that is a websocket, that looks like this: ws://<server>/job/<job_id>/ws.
How do I use Flask to proxy to this backend websocket, such that a browser can hit Flask and receive both the static content and also the websocket data?
I want to use Flask as there is some custom logic that needs to happen in my proxying logic.
